# ajax status dialog appears on every p:progressBar's update interval

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a progress bar in my UI. I have a common ajax loading pop up dialog which i display during the ajax updates e.g i show it in onclick attribute of a button and hide it on oncomplete.
But the problem is that the loading dialog appears in case of the progress bar on it's every interval update for a small time and then again disappears. It looks bad in UI. What i want is to avoid this loading dialog to be shown during every update interval on my progress bar. I have to set ajax=true for my progress bar because i am reading progress from the backing bean.
May be is there a way to use any Jquery function e.g ajaxstart()? I am using primefaces 3.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with Jquery's ajaxStart() like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inProgress;
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() 
    {
        if ( inProgress )
        {
            $( '#main-status-dialog' ).hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

and on button click, i am setting it to true as "inProgress = true;"

Answer (score 1):

First of all **ajax status** is global for ajax requests. If there are more than one ajax events in your view and some of them takes small amount of time to be load and no need to show progress bar you have some options:

1. If there are not so much ajax events in your view, than set
   `global="false"`which one you don't want to be updated.
2. Use [blockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml) for components that you want to show ajax status.You can use it like:

```
<p:dataTable id="blockMe" ...>
   <p:commandButton id="save" ...>
</p:dataTable>

<p:blockUI block="blockMe" trigger="save" />
```

Or like this:

```
<p:pickList widgetVar="blockMe" ...>
   <p:ajax event="transfer" onstart="blockMe.show()" oncomplete="blockMe.hide()" ...>
</p:pickList>

<p:blockUI widgetVar="blockMe">
   LOADING<br />
   <p:graphicImage name="img/ajaxloadingbar.gif"/>
</p:blockUI>
```

Comment: +1 for `global="false"`. But i think your answer is very confusing because of its general nature. Go deeper with the specific problem. You should clarify to set the _global_ attribute on _progressBar_ to suppress _ajaxStatus_ trigging. A code example would be helpful too.

Comment: Agree with @irieill. there is no globla attribute supported by progress bar. My problem is only to hide ajax loading dialog on update interval of progress bar.